# Varying limit of votes per day

Tags: bug, voting

The [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) states:

> You can vote on posts 30 times per UTC day, plus 10 more times on questions only.

However I find that to not be true. The other day, I did get a message banner that I have only 5 votes left. Any additional vote reduced those 5 votes by one, and after that was reduced to 0, no more voting, also not when trying to vote on questions. Total vote count was 35, I believe as I had voted on 5 questions, too.

It appears that you only get the 10 extra votes on questions, if you vote on them before you get the message that you are starting to run out.

Is my understanding how that works correct, and is there a reason for this, or is it just a glitch of how that is coded up? It seems to be a bug to me that the order in which you vote on things makes a difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The formula is a bit more complicated than "30+10". If you don't vote enough on questions first (i.e., before you've voted on 25 answers), you may only get as few as 30 total votes that day. It's confusing, but that's how it was designed. The intent was obviously to reward users who vote on questions (which get less votes than answers on most sites) with "bonus votes". I assume the intent of this particular design was to have a system that isn't in your face while voting, though I can't justify the hidden complexity completely.

See [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/323179) for a detailed explanation.